# Unique reduced subscheme $(Y, \mathcal O_Y)$ of $X$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an algebraic variety over an algebraically closed field $K$.  The definition here of algebraic variety is: $X$ is a locally ringed space of $K$-algebras which has a finite open cover by affines, affine here meaning the space of *maximal* ideals of a finitely generated $K$-algebra.  Also $X$ is reduced and separated.

A closed subscheme of $X$ is a pair $(Y, \mathcal O_Y)$, together with a morphism of varieties $(Y, \mathcal O_Y) \rightarrow (X, \mathcal O_X)$ such that the stalk maps $\mathcal O_{X,x} \rightarrow \mathcal O_{Y,x}$ are surjective for all $x \in Y$.

Borel writes in *Linear Algebraic Groups*: if $Y$ is a closed subspace of $X$, then there is a unique reduced subscheme $(Y, \mathcal O_Y)$ of $X$.  $\mathcal O_Y$ is the sheaf associated to the presheaf $U \cap Y \rightarrow \mathcal O_X(U)/I_U(Y)$, where $I_U(Y)$ is the ideal of functions on $U$ vanishing on $Y \cap U$.

A bit of explanation: $X$ is reduced, so you can actually think of $\mathcal O_X(U)$ as a ring of functions $U \rightarrow K$.  For example, if $X = \textrm{Max } A$ is affine, then this is the notion of 'regular functions' in Hartshorne.

My question is, how is this presheaf well defined?  If, say $U \subseteq V$ are open with $U \cap Y = V \cap Y$, I'd like to say that $\mathcal O_X(U)/I_U(Y) \cong \mathcal O_X(V)/I_V(Y)$, an isomorphism being induced by restriction from $V$ to $U$.  Certainly there is an injection $\mathcal O_X(V)/I_V(Y) \rightarrow \mathcal O_X(U)/I_U(Y)$.  The problem is that the restriction map $\mathcal O_X(V) \rightarrow \mathcal O_X(U)$ isn't surjective, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Affine localy, the statement that

$$\mathcal O_X(V) \to \mathcal O_X(U)/I_U(Y)$$

is surjective, becomes the following statement about localizations:

The map $A \to A_f/I_f$ is surjective if $(I,f)=A$. Let us proof this. Note that $(I,f)=A$ implies $(I,f^s)=A$ for any $s \geq 1$.

Now let $\frac{a}{f^s} \in A_f$. We can write $1=x+bf^s$ with $x \in I, b \in A$ and thus obtain

$$\frac{a}{f^s}=\frac{a}{f^s}(x+bf^s)=\frac{ax}{f^s}+ab.$$

We have $\frac{ax}{f^s} \in I_f$, hence, modulo $I_f$, we have $\frac{a}{f^s}=ab$, i.e. $ab \in A$ is a desired pre-image.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. If $V = \textrm{Max } A$ is affine, and $U$ is say, principal open, and $\mathcal O_X(U) = A_f$, why can I conclude that $I_U(Y)$ is the localization of an ideal which is comaximal with $(f)$?

Comment: Okay wait that's just the nullstellensatz, never mind.

Comment: Indeed. $U \cap Y = V \cap Y$ translates into $V(I,f)=\emptyset$, i.e. $(I,f)=(1)$ by the Nullstellensatz.